# Share files between two Win8 machines

Tags: windows-8, file-sharing

How can I share files between two or more Windows 8 computers, while blocking internet access? They should be connected to a home router which is connected to internet. But I don't want any of sharing computers to access the internet through that connection.

Comment: Consider using a NAS device, this way if any single PC is down or off the others will still be able to access the files that were shared. Most NAS devices, like the Synology for example, will allow you to create usernames to limit access to certain files/folders.

Comment: Is there any real solution?

Answer (score 1):

One easy method:

A gateway is a node (a router) on a TCP/IP network that serves as an access point to another network (the Internet).  Go into the IP settings for the computers you don't want to have Internet access.  Change the IP address of the Default gateway to a bogus unused IP address and they will not have access to the Internet.

For this to work you will also have to set the IP address and Subnet mask of them as well.